Is it faster to transfer data if I connect an external SSD to mac thunderbolt USB-C rather than to mac USB-A (if my mac only has 1 USB-A port)?
I have a mac mini, and an external SSD that only has a USB-A port.
So, currently, I use a USB-A to USB-A cable to connect the SSD to the mac to transfer data.
Now, if I use a USB-A to USB-C cable to connect the SSD to the mac, will I be able to transfer the data faster ?
I know that mac thunderbolt (USB-C) port can transfer data much faster than mac USB-A port.
But, my SSD only has a USB-A port and does NOT have a USB-C port.
So, is it still faster if I use the USB-A to USB-C cable to connect my SSD to the mac to transfer data ?

There is the shape of the connector, and there is the transfer speed supported by the SSD. What does the data sheet of the SSD say about the second?

What SSD? It may be limited to much the same speed as the USB-A port.

No - the limiting factor will be the USB-A bottleneck on the device. Newer cables and connectors slow down to match old legacy protocol and speeds even when you’re using a newer fancy cable and connection on the computer end.
